# How to use icons in both .vue files and .jsx files?

Tags: vue.js, jsx

I am using `unplugin-icons` to automatically import icons.The icon displays normally in `.vue`, but not in `.jsx`. How should I configure it to display in `.vue` and `.jsx` at the same time?

```js
export default [
  vue(),
  vueJsxPlugin(),
  AutoImport({
    resolvers: [ElementPlusResolver()],
    imports: ['vue', 'vue-router', 'pinia'],
    dirs: ['src/store/**/*'],
    vueTemplate: true,
    defaultExportByFilename: false,
    dts: './config/auto-imports.d.ts',
    eslintrc: {
      enabled: true,
      filepath: './config/.eslintrc-auto-import.json',
      globalsPropValue: true
    }
  }),
  Components({
    resolvers: [
      ElementPlusResolver(),
      VueUseComponentsResolver(),
      IconsResolver({
        prefix: false,
        enabledCollections: ['ep']
      })
    ],
    dirs: ['src/components', 'src/layouts'],
    directoryAsNamespace: false,
    dts: './config/components.d.ts'
  }),
  Icons({
    autoInstall: true,
    compiler: 'vue3'
  })
];
```

I have also raised this issue in the [discussions](https://github.com/unplugin/unplugin-icons/discussions/313) in unplugin-icons, but no one has responded to me so far.

environment

- vite: 4.4.5
- unplugin-icons: 0.17.0
- unplugin-auto-import: 0.16.6
- unplugin-vue-components: 0.25.1
- vue: 3.3.4
- @vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx: 3.0.2

What I expect is that the icon can run normally in both `.vue` files and `.jsx` files.

In fact, the icon can only be displayed in the `.vue` file.

Comment: "What I expect " - why? You specified it for vue only. Did you try to add another Icons entry for jsx?

Comment: @Estus Flask Thank you very much for your reply, how should I specify jsx?

Comment: `Icons({
    autoInstall: true,
    compiler: 'vue3'
  }),   Icons({
    autoInstall: true,
    compiler: 'jsx',
  jsx: 'react'
  })`. Notice that jsx in vue isn't exactly the same. If you need it to support JSX in Vue, it's possible it's not supported at all

Comment: @Estus Flask Thank you very much for your recovery. I tried it but it still didn’t work. I used `@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx` plug-in to use `jsx` in Vue.

Comment: It's unclear why you have .jsx then, this is unconventional. Vue SFC are .vue. If you use jsx there, it's handled with script lang=jsx, I'd expect the lib to work this way

Comment: @Estus Flask My colleague introduced `@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx` into the project and used `jsx` to write the page. As a result, the icon in the `.jsx` file did not appear after I used `unplugin-icons`.